# Enable FlipView only when specific UI element is touched

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, flipview

I have a FlipView control which is used to navigate between two pages. I would like to have the FlipView control only animating to the second page when a specific UI element on the first page is dragged.

I managed to disable the FlipView by setting

```
ManipulationMode = "None";
```

On the first FlipViewItem.

I then tried to re-enable the FlipView when the UI element inside the first FlipViewItem was touched (ManipulationStarted event). The problem I'm facing, is that the ManipulationStarted event is not getting triggered, and therefor have no way of enabling the FlipView when needed... Is there an easy way to fix this?